# Story where the main character can seduce any female

Tags: story-identification

I read this story about 2 years ago.

A class gets transported to another world. There, the main character gets abandoned for some reason. He can seduce any female character. He gets a butterfly friend. There is also another character which can seduce any man.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved if you went through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a bit thin on distinctive details (except for the butterfly friend); you should check out the [suggestions for a good story-id question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) to see if they help you remember any additional details to [edit] into your question.

Comment: Where did you read it? Is it an online story or something printed. Was it adult (containing explicit sex) or something less racey?

Comment: A story about a debonaire sophisticate who's irresistible to women? Yikes. It sounds like my diary has been leaked to the press

Comment: Is this a short story or a manga? This sounds like an *isegai* kind of story.

Comment: A class, you mean a school class? If so, the combination of school kids and sex would suggest Piers Anthony. So I haven't read it.

Comment: Ash Ketchum? BUTTERFREE!! Gotta catch 'em all!

Comment: @Moriarty Piers Anthony was my first thought, though offhand I can't think of any of his books that match.

Comment: This is probably a light novel.  I found a manga with the same plot a few months back.  If it is the same, the class was summoned, and everyone found out everyone's abilities.  the mc's ability was outed to the class, and he was avoided/kicked out as a result.  the name of his power suggested generally doing lewd things to women.  I don't think the manga had gotten to explicit things yet, but it was only a couple chapters in.  it is mentioned that the first thing the mc uses his power on is a butterfly.

Comment: @shufly but in that comic there is no other ppl can seduce and the time Beb ask is 2 years ago

Comment: @someoneuseless yes, which is why i said it is probably the light novel.  it usually takes time before a light novel gets turned into a manga, and are further along as a result. Since besides the time frame and other character it fits, i figure it is at least a place to start looking. The site i normally check is down, otherwise i would have tried to get a title to check for a light novel to post, rather than the comment.

Comment: The site i normally use came back up, so i was able to find the manga, and the light novel from there.  Glancing through the first few chapters I believe it is the same.

Answer (score 4):

I believe you are looking for [Because I Was Excluded Out of the Class Transfer, I Decided to Steal My Classmate’s Lover.](https://www.novelupdates.com/series/because-i-was-excluded-out-of-the-class-transfer-i-decided-to-steal-my-classmates-lover/) I feel I probably don't need to mention this based on the title alone, but it is NSFW.

The main character has the skill [Underling Training (Lunatic Sexual)]. This skill allows him to "train" women.  He is then forced out of the group by another character, who said his skill made the girls in the class nervous.

A couple chapters in, the main character has a butterfly who is his underling because of the skill.  I did not see the character who could seduce any man, but I only skimmed the first few chapters.  The site i found it on has the translations for the first few chapters from 2016, so at least the two years ago you said you read it.