# Isekai manga where the MC can enslave anyone

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a manga where the MC and his class were transported from another world but he was the weakest in his class so he vanished from the castle. His ability allows him to enslave anyone so one by one he enslaved every girl in the class by having sex with them and making them submit to him. In the former last chapter he becomes a butler in the castle undercover to enslave every girl in his class.

It is similar to the mangas "My Classmate is the Prince’s Knight" or "My Job was a Slavemancer".

Comment: I believe the isekai tag is appropriate for this question

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is *Because I Was Excluded Out Of The Class Transfer, I Decided To Steal My Classmate's Lover*, which was also my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/222725/101936)

The main character has the skill [Underling Training (Lunatic Sexual)]. This skill allows him to "train" women. He is then forced out of the group by another character, who said his skill made the girls in the class nervous.

After  he is kicked out of the group, he starts using the ability on his female classmates. At the end of chapter 4/beginning of chapter 5 the few he had enslaved helped him get back into the castle by making him be a butler.